# C++ Builder Datasnap How to access Server Object List

Tags: c++, c++builder, 3-tier

I am making a 3 tier application in c++ builder XE3 with Datasnaps and I am working on the middle tier part for now.
but I have one problem, the server needs to show the information from the client too.
lets say if the client pushes two ints say 5 and 5 and the server should sum them up.
the server should show it in its GUI also.

long story short how do I access the ServerObject list which contain my server methods,
where is it stored and can I even access it?

this is probably the most vague question I ever posted, but I can't explain any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it myself. the objects are accessible at the ServerPrepare Event. every time there is interaction with the server the object is available in DSPrepareEventObject->MethodInstance
that must be casted to a instance of your Serverclass.

EDIT: or even better all forms are global objects :/